# Service not starting after reboot

Tags: ubuntu, service

I have installed nginx and gunicorn and have moved the scripts in /etc/init.d/ folder in ubuntu . However for some reason even after using update-rc.d -f nginx defaults the service is not starting on server reboot.

However it starts with no problem manually  /etc/init.d/nginx start

This is the Linux Version: 3.0.0-15-server 
ubuntu release: 11.10

I even checked the log /var/log/boot.log and there is nothing in it with regards to any error.

Answer (score 1):

Those services were managed by upstart for me on Ubuntu 12.04, corresponding therefore to files of type `/etc/init/nginx.conf`.

The problem was that for some reason, in the `.conf` file the `start` stanza was commented out:

```
#start on runlevel [2345]
```

Uncommenting solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

The command to add symlinks to a service in default runleves is:

```
update-rc.d foobar defaults
```

Taken from the manpage of update-rc.d (man update-rc.d)

Comment: thats not helpful. As this is what I have been trying to do and it doesn; work. The service doesn't start when the server reboots.

Comment: So after spending almost 3 hours on it I realized a workaround for the service to be started is by manually adding the files in the /etc/rc.local file with the command one wants to run. 

So I added the lines;

sudo /etc/init.d/nginx start
sudo /etc/init.d/supervisor start

and all is set, but I still wonder why was it not working with the update-rc.d which is I hope the correct way for running services on server bootup.

Comment: The symlinks in /etc/rc2.d/ are ok? Are the scripts in /etc/init.d/ executable? Can you paste some ls output?

Answer (score 0):

`sysv-rc-conf` then locate your service and enable it for all desired run-levels.